# How was I murdered by Nyan Cat?

Tags: terraria

I was fighting the solar pillar with the Meowmere sword, and I was doing really well, I had actually just killed it, when I died. Now, dying's not a huge deal to me, especially considering I die all the time, but I happened to look at the death message and it said:

> Darth McButtkix's vital organs were ruptured by Meowmere.

How did that happen? I thought my nyan cat minions were supposed to hurt my enemies, not me. In the past, I could run into them all I wanted without getting hurt, but for whatever reason, this time they killed me. Is this a bug? Or is there a Meowmere mechanic that I'm missing?

Picture for proof:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The problem here is clearly the username: "Darth McButtkix" xD

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One of the enemies which you would have been fighting near the solar pillar would have been a [Selenian.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Selenian)

[image: a selenian - a small creature with flaming hair and swords]

They have a special ability which allows them to *reflect*, among other things,

> - Sword beams, such as those from the Terra Blade

or of course the Meowmere.

You were unlucky enough to be hit by your own projectile. As the Meowmere has the highest base damage of any melee weapon, the reflected projectile can deal over 300 damage. Since you would have been on lower health due to all the enemies of the lunar events, this attack would have easily 1-shot you.

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day! I had no idea these enemies could reflect damage...

Comment: @JonahBishop "Live and learn. Die, and learn faster" - MTrek manual

Comment: [Projectile reflecting enemies, such as the Selenian and closed Mimics, will reflect the cat projectile.](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meowmere)